# Jquery accordion loaded via ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

So im working on a site that uses ajax to load content between pages, but the javascript inside those pages stops working when its loaded, even though it works just fine if i visit the page directly.

Heres the index page

http://tinyurl.com/82exd3u

if you click "services", you can see it it loads with the accordion sidebar not working. And when i visit the page directly, it works fine.

http://tinyurl.com/7jfjek8

heres the ajax code im using (tried using live, but it didnt do the job)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav').live('click', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href')+" #content";
        $('#content').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
        return false
    }); 
});
```

and i removed the document() ready part from the accordion code hoping that would do the trick, but still nothing.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: You know that a page built like that will most likely loose on Google rankings?

Comment: Please note that `live()` is deprecated.

Comment: yeah i know it wont help with google ranking, but its how the client want the site built

Comment: did you fix it. please share i m facing the same :(

Comment: It appears you've removed the "ajaxyness" of those pages?

Comment: @user1377024 it works just fine when I load it.

Answer (score 0):

In the index file, when the body element loads it tries to call initialize(); which is not defined. That must be the reason why javascript stops working. Check the onLoad attribute of the body element.

Also check your urls to your JS and CSS files, two of them are not working:

> ```
>  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
>
>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
> ```